# How to add a DataTemplate to a ToolTip for a wpf ComboBox using a Style

Tags: wpf, combobox, tooltip, datatemplate

I am trying to format a ToolTip in a ComboBox. The following XAML is correctly picking up the value needed for the ToolTip, but not the DataTemplate.

```
<DataTemplate DataType = "ToolTip">
            <TextBlock Width = "200" TextWrapping = "Wrap" Text = "{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <Style x:Key = "RadComboBoxStyle1" TargetType = "{x:Type telerik:RadComboBox}">         
            <Setter Property = "Width" Value = "140" />
            <Setter Property = "DisplayMemberPath" Value = "DisplayMember" />
            <Setter Property = "SelectedValuePath" Value = "SelectedValue" />
            <Setter Property = "ToolTip" Value = "{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=SelectedItem.Description}" />
        </Style>
```

I'm sure it can't be as difficult as I'm making it :)

Thanks
Jeremy

Answer (score 1):

You could just define the tooltip with

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBox.ToolTip>
       <!-- custom tip -->
    </ComboBox.ToolTip>
</ComboBox>
```

but otherwise maybe try:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
```

Comment: That doesn't work. I really want to do it within the style - I've got about 20 comboboxes on the form, and would rather change them universally from within the style than have to touch each one.